# Possible to undelete apps from dashboard?

Tags: google-fabric

We have some legacy apps on the Fabric dashboard though not sure if we'd ever needed them again so we could delete them from the dashboard.

If we do republish them, can we undelete them later?

If not, could we get another Fabric key to republish them with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you re-onboard the deleted app, by installing one of the kits, and building and running your app, it will re-appear on your Fabric dashboard. The historical data won't be available though. If you recently deleted an app by accident and need to restore the original app and data, we can help you out at support@fabric.io

Comment: Reaching out the support and asking to enable removed application worked really well, they usually reply within the next ~24 hours. I'm not sure why Fabric Android SDK doesn't reenable the application in Fabric automatically when you open that application next time for which you removed the application profile in Fabric.